# Indexing the list in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
record=['MAT', '90', '62', 'ENG', '92','88']

course='MAT'
```

suppose i want to get the marks for MAT or ENG what do i do? I just know how to find the index of the course which is new[4:10].index(course). Idk how to get the marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
i = record.index('MAT')
grades = record[i+1:i+3]
```

In this case `i` is the index/position of the `'MAT'` or whichever course, and grades are the items in a slice comprising the two slots after the course name.

You could also put it in a function:

```
def get_grades(course):
    i = record.index(course)
    return record[i+1:i+3]
```

Then you can just pass in the course name and get back the grades.

```
>>> get_grades('ENG')
['92', '88']
>>> get_grades('MAT')
['90', '62']
>>>
```

## Edit

If you want to get a string of the two grades together instead of a list with the individual values you can modify the function as follows:

```
def get_grades(course):
    i = record.index(course)
    return ' '.join("'{}'".format(g) for g in record[i+1:i+3])
```

Comment: elethan is there a way i can make my final answer are '90' '92'

Comment: @Bob it can output `"'90' '92'"` if you wan't, or `'90 92'` but `'90' '92'` on it's own (as two strings) will not work. It will be concatinated to `'9092'`.

Comment: how would i do that" '90' '92'"

Comment: @Bob OK, try the function under **Edit**

Answer (score 0):

You can use index function ( see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/176921/) and later get next indexes, but I think you should use a dictionary.